# nginx configuration redirect a subdomain to open directory

Tags: nginx

i already create a sub.domain.com

and i need when i hit sub.domain.com, it will redirect to open this folder `/app/image`

like this http://animorphsfanforum.com/fanart/2064/

listing the file like that.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  api.test123.com;      

}
```

i tried to do like this..

http://nginxlibrary.com/enable-directory-listing/

but i dont know this usage

```
access_log  /var/...........................;
    root   /path/to/root;
    location / {
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just do something like this and this one run well

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```